# Extracting the value of a hidden variable from a website using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I want to extract the variable of a hidden variable from a website like facebook.com.
How can i do this using cURL.

Thanks

Comment: @SabeenMalik $ch = curl_init ("http://www.facebook.com/nike");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$abc = curl_exec ($ch);
preg_match("/input type=\"hidden\" name=\"fb_dtsg\" value=\"(.*?)\"/", $abc, $fb_dtsg);

Answer (score 1):

*PLEASE* see the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). You should *NEVER* try to use Regex to parse HTML. It doesn't work. Use the PHP Document Object Model to parse the document instead: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php).

[phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) is a **great** tool for what you want to do, and it essentially provides you with the familiar jQuery API within PHP (CSS selectors, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression:

```
/<input.+?type=['"]?hidden['"]?.+?value=['"]?(.+?)['"]?/si
```

I don't know how to make this regexp not depending place of value.